# upload file to google drive without manually signed in with oauth python

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I want to write a simple script that every day uploads a file to my google drive,
but all the examples that I find require me to manually select the account.
I have settings.yaml and client_secrets.json files.
the settings.yaml is from [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/oauth.html)
and the configuration of the client is according to [this manule](https://d35mpxyw7m7k7g.cloudfront.net/bigdata_1/Get+Authentication+for+Google+Service+API+.pdf)
how do I do that?
this is my code:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
file1 = drive.CreateFile()
file1.SetContentFile('/home/Desktop/file.xml')
file1.Upload()
```

settings.yaml file:

```
cient_config_backend: settings
client_config:
  client_id: some_client_id
  client_secret: some_client_secret

save_credentials: True
save_credentials_backend: file
save_credentials_file: credentials.json
#save_credentials_file: client_secrets.json

get_refresh_token: True

oauth_scope:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install
```

client_secrets.json file:

```
{
  "installed":{"client_id":"some_client_id",
               "project_id":"project_id",
               "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
               "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
               "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
               "client_secret":"some_client_secret",
               "redirect_uris":["http://localhost"]}
}
```

Comment: Your using installed application credentials. Its gong to require that the user authenticate your application by selecting their account and approving your access. You need access to private user data.    You cant just have access to your users private data without them granting you permission.

Comment: If your using your personal google drive account then you should be using service account authentication.